# SQLite Persist Update

Tags: sqlite, persistence, uwp

I'm using SQLite on Windows UWP (10).

This is what I am doing:

Open connection
Begin Transaction
Update row
Commit Transaction
Close connection

And yet, the value in the database is not actually written to the table. When I reload the record (after disconnecting and reconnecting, or not disconnecting) the value remains from before I called the update.

Is there something extra I need to do? In DB Browser for SQLite, there is a menu item called "Write Changes". What does that do? Just a normal commit? In the browser, the changes are only committed if I click on this menu item.

Also, I put a trace on the connection, and this is what came up:

Executing: begin transaction

Executing: UPDATE
    'TaskManagement.TaskInfo'
SET
    StatusKey = @StatusKey, ProbAddDttm = @ProbAddDttm, ProbCode = @ProbCode,   ProbPriority = @ProbPriority,   ProbGroup = @ProbGroup, ProbInsp = @ProbInsp,   Activity = @Activity,   UpdateDttm = @UpdateDttm,   Asset = @Asset, Address = @Address, TaskStartDttm = @TaskStartDttm, MaintenanceScheduleSetup = @MaintenanceScheduleSetup,   MaintenanceScheduleBatch = @MaintenanceScheduleBatch,   ProbZone = @ProbZone,   ProbContractor = @ProbContractor,   ProbNotes = @ProbNotes, JobCompleted = @JobCompleted,   Resolution = @Resolution,   Result = @Result,   ActType = @ActType, Complaint = @Complaint, BudgetNo = @BudgetNo,   Contractor = @Contractor,   MapLocCorrect = @MapLocCorrect, FollowUpWorkRequired = @FollowUpWorkRequired,   Condition = @Condition, ActPriority = @ActPriority, ExpectedVersion = @ExpectedVersion, EmailProbOriginator = @EmailProbOriginator, IsBug = @IsBug, IsCompletePendingCheckIn = @IsCompletePendingCheckIn
WHERE
    TaskInfoKey = @PrimaryKey
  0: 63711ec4-57d0-4a23-8595-0022b757af44
  1: 6
  2: 2013-06-03 08:56:39:117
  3: 13
  4: 2
  5: 17
  6: 24
  7: 
  8: 2015-11-10 04:05:09:502
  9: 
  10: 
  11: 2013-06-03 08:56:39:117
  12: 
  13: 
  14: 
  15: 
  16: Test this mofo!
  17: 2013-08-15 12:13:24:620
  18: 
  19: 
  20: 
  21: 
  22: 
  23: 4
  24: False
  25: False
  26: 
  27: 
  28: 3
  29: False
  30: False
  31: False

Executing: Commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end, the problem was that I was not passing the parameters in to the library correctly. The connection's CreateCommand method only allows you to pass in the command text, and an array of objects. This is incorrect because that means you can't name the parameters. So, I consider this a piece of missing functionality in this particular implementation of SQLite for UWP.

Secondly, this should have errored! None of the parameter names I mentioned above were passed in to the command, and yet when I ran it, no exception was thrown. So, I consider this to be the second bug in the implementation.

I fixed it like this:

```
        var command = _Connection.CreateCommand(commandText, new object[0]);

        if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {

                if (parameter.ParameterValue is DateTime)
                {
                    parameter.ParameterValue = ((DateTime)parameter.ParameterValue).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:fff");
                }

                command.Bind(parameter.ParameterName, parameter.ParameterValue);
            }
        }

        return command;
```